# ElasticSearch not able to return data going above 10,000 offset, I am not allowed to make index level changes. Can't use Scroll API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running ES query step by step for different offset and limit. For example 100 to 149, then 150 to 199, then 200 to 249.. and so on.
When I keep offset+limit more than 10,000 then getting below exception:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "query_phase_execution_exception",
            "reason": "Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10001]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level parameter."
         }
      ],
      "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason": "all shards failed",
      "phase": "query",
      "grouped": true,
      "failed_shards": [
         {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "xyz",
            "node": "123",
            "reason": {
               "type": "query_phase_execution_exception",
               "reason": "Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10001]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level parameter."
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "status": 500
}
```

I know we can solve this by increasing the "max_result_window". I tried it and it helped too. I increased it to 15,000 then 30,000. But I am not allowed to make index level changes.
So, I changed it back to default one 10,000.

How can I solve this problem? This query is getting hit by an API call.

Comment: Read this, for newer versions of elasticsearch:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-request-search-after.html

Comment: I can't move to newer version of elasticsearch, which make it difficult to use new functionalities. Can you suggest something which can solve this problem in 2.2.1

Comment: Then i don't think it is doable without a field that you could sort on. If your query was something with sort on some field like timestamp, then you could change your query for every page (timestamp> last_timestamp), keeping the last_timestamp in session or request.

Comment: I do not understand this. How a sorting technique will help the max_result_window limit? I agree i'll get sorted result, but still the limit on number of result will remain the same.

Comment: instead of increasing the offset, you will then change the query to something like: timestamp > timestamp_of_last_result. You will then stay at the same offset and limit. Hence, not reaching max_size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approach which worked for me-

1. increasing the max_result_window
2. Using filter
   a. by knowing the unique id of data records
   b. by knowing the time frame

**First approach** was applied using below

```
PUT /index/_settings
{ "max_result_window" : 10000 }
```

This worked and solved my problem, but number of records is dynamic element and increasing very fast. So, it is not good to keep increasing this window. Also in my case we use index on sharing basis. So,this change will effect all the users or group on this shared index. So, we moved on to second approach.

**Second approach**
Part1: First I applied filter on last update timestamp and if record count is greater than 10K then I divide the time frame by half and keep doing it until it reaches count less than 10k.

Part2: As same data is also available in OLTP, I got the complete list of a unique identifier and sorted it. Then applied filter on that identifier and only fetched data in range of 10K. Once 10K data is fetched using pagination, then change the filter and move to next batch of 10k data.

Part3: Applied sorting on last updated timestamp and started fetching data using pagination. Once record count reaches 10k, get the timestamp of 9999 record and apply greater_than filter on identifier and then fetch next 10k records.

All mentioned solution helped me. But I selected the Part3 of second approach. As it is easy to implement and give a sorted data quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider scroll API - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-request-scroll.html

This is also suggested in [manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html)

Comment: Consider my comment in question, can't use scroll api. Also need to solve this without version upgrade. Consider 2.2.1

Comment: I'm afraid you dont have any other options. Also this API is available in 2.2.1 ; the link i provided is to 2.2.1 manual